# get checkboxlist selected values under li tag

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have checkboxlist which gets values from database. And there is one label which gets selected values in checkboxes. I want each selected value to come under 
li tag like this

value1

value2

However currently it is coming like this [Please clink linK](http://healthsaviour.com/snowsnap.jpg) (I don't have enough reputation so can't upload image here. Please go to that link)

VB code

```
For Each chk As ListItem In servicesList.Items
            If chk.Selected = True Then
                selectedServices.Text = String.Concat("<li>" + selectedServices.Text + chk.Value + "</li>")
            End If
        Next
```

How do I make it to work properly as I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As below,

```
    Dim selectedServices as String = String.empty
    For Each chk As ListItem In servicesList.Items
        If chk.Selected = True Then
            selectedServices &= "<li>" + chk.Text + "</li>"
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Here selectedservices is a label . Are you sure this will work?

Comment: Here I used selectedServices as a string variable. if there is a label in your case, you can set label at last like, lbl.text = selectedServices

Comment: May be you can rename my string variable to something like, Dim s as string = string.empty

Comment: At last you set your label selectedServices.Text = s

Comment: Your solutions worked perfectly for me but there is minor problem. with this selected value also inserting in database. And one of my page has listview control which gets this data from database. Now there it is creating one empty li & then the selected values come. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: May be I remove listview from there and fetch label values directly can solve this problem

Comment: It creates an empty li only when there is any blank item in checkboxlist. If there are 3 items in checkboxlist, it creates only 3 li. If instead of 3, it creates 4 there is an issue. So can you please confirm this and let me know what happen.

Comment: I prefer to store comma separated values in database. And when read from database split it by comma. Let me know if you need any example, I will send you

Comment: If It is comma saperated then while fetching it is it possible to show a single value in <li> tag. because that is my design format

Comment: Please go to this link http://healthsaviour.com/hospital-details?hospitalID=448799 & scroll down you will find SERVICES AVAILABLE section. see under 3 services which I selected but prior it shows blank li. I seen this in firbug that empty li created with the same id which I have used for listview control

Comment: anyways If I don't use listview then my problem gets solved with this solution. Thanks so much my most important work done by you..

Comment: If you like my answer, can you please vote up this answer?

Comment: Hey. while retrieving this data how can I make checkbox selected?

Comment: You can get field from database, which may be multiple li tags. Split that field using li tag. Once you get plain text, loop through checkbox items and compare that name with plain text which you get. If matched display selected. Let me know if you want example.

Comment: Please explain in example

Comment: Ok. I will provide you, before that can you give me whole string which is stored in database?

Comment: I make a new post & mention it there properly. Answer me on that

Comment: One more thing, I see your another post "Forms data not updating", I answered, just before someone else has answered that and you accepted so that is good, but then you or may be someone else has vote it down? So just want to ask you whether you vote it down?

Comment: The person who said "It should be comment" might down voted. But for me that answer which I marked worked.

Comment: For now, I don't have that much of reputation so that I can comment, that's why I just share my thought as an answer. Once I will earned sufficient reputation for comments, definitely I will add it as an comments. Anyways, he has to understand, I am a new user and try to give best solutions to people.

Comment: Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789694/get-checkbx-values-selected-from-database