# Get checkbx values selected from database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have users form in which they can select some values from checkbox list & values selected in that stores in database in li form. Now I want when users wants to update their form they should be able to see the values checked they have selected earlier.

here is my code.

Insert Form

```
Private Sub PopulateServices()
        Using conn As New MySqlConnection()
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager _
                .ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString()
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from services"
                cmd.Connection = conn
                conn.Open()
                Using sdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While sdr.Read()
                        Dim item As New ListItem()
                        item.Text = sdr("serviceName").ToString()
                        item.Value = sdr("serviceName").ToString()
                        'item.Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr("IsSelected"))
                        servicesList.Items.Add(item)
                    End While
                End Using
                conn.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
    End Sub

Dim selectedServices As String = String.Empty
        For Each chk As ListItem In servicesList.Items
            If chk.Selected = True Then
                selectedServices &= "<li>" + chk.Text + "</li>"
            End If
        Next

Try
            Dim str1 As String = "INSERT INTO hospitals (`hospitalID`,`username`, `password`) values ('" + ID + "', '"selectedServices.ToString + "', '" + mobileNumber + "', '" + membersAutoPassword.Text + "')"

            Dim str2 As MySqlDataReader
            Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
            Dim command As New MySqlCommand
            command.CommandText = str1
            command.Connection = con
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            con.Open()
            str2 = command.ExecuteReader
            con.Close()
            Response.Redirect("business-added.aspx")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex)
        End Try
```

On User Profile page after login they should be able to see what options they have selected. Hence there is a option for users to update their details again

UPDATED
User Profile Page

```
Private Sub list_business_hospital_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
         If Not IsPostBack Then
                Try
                    Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM  hospitals WHERE username='" + Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies("chkusername").Value) + "';"
                    con.Open()
                    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(str, con)
                    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Dim dt As New DataTable
                    Dim lblservice As New Label
                    For Each chk As ListItem In servicesList.Items
                        If chk.Selected = True Then
                            lblservice.Text = String.Concat(lblservice.Text + ",", chk.Value)

                        End If
                    Next

                    da.Fill(dt)
                    con.Close()
                    TextId.Text = dt.Rows(0)("hospitalID").ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
                    Response.Write(ex)
                End Try

Private Sub PopulateServices()
        Using conn As New MySqlConnection()
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager _
                .ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString()
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from services"
                cmd.Connection = conn
                conn.Open()
                Using sdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While sdr.Read()
                        Dim item As New ListItem()
                        item.Text = sdr("serviceName").ToString()
                        item.Value = sdr("serviceName").ToString()
                        'item.Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr("IsSelected"))
                        servicesList.Items.Add(item)
                    End While
                End Using
                conn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

Private Sub updateInfo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles updateInfo.Click
        Try
            Dim con As New MySqlConnection
            Dim query As New MySqlCommand
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager _
                .ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString()
            query.Connection = con
            con.Open()

            Dim selectedServices As String = String.Empty
            For Each chk As ListItem In servicesList.Items
                If selectedServices.Contains("<li>" & chk.Text & "</li>") Then
                    'display item as selected
                    chk.Selected = True
                End If

            Next

            query.CommandText = "UPDATE hospitals SET name = '" + businessName.Text + "', contactPerson = '" + contactPerson.Text + "', websiteName = '" + websiteName.Text + "', email = '" + emailName.Text + "', phone1 = '" + phone1.Text + "', phone2 = '" + phone2.Text + "', mobileNumber = '" + mobile.Text + "', buildingName = '" + buildingName.Text + "', streetName = '" + address.Text + "', landmark = '" + landmark.Text + "', areaName = '" + areaName.Text + "', city = '" + suburb.Text + "', state = '" + state.Text + "', zipCode = '" + zip.Text + "', overview = '" + overview.Text + "', registration = '" + regNo.Text + "', establishment = '" + foundation.Text + "', founder = '" + founderName.Text + "', generalBed = '" + GeneralBeds.Text + "', icuBed = '" + ICU.Text + "', consultancyFees = '" + consultinfees.Text + "', mondayFrom = '" + mondayFrom.Text + "', mondayTo = '" + mondayTo.Text + "', tuesdayFrom = '" + tuesdayFrom.Text + "', tuesdayTo = '" + tuesdayTo.Text + "', wednesdayFrom = '" + wedFrom.Text + "', wednesdayTo = '" + wedTo.Text + "', thursdayFrom = '" + thursdayFrom.Text + "', thursdayTo = '" + thursdayTo.Text + "', fridayFrom = '" + fridayFrom.Text + "', fridayTo = '" + fridayTo.Text + "', saturdayFrom = '" + saturdayFrom.Text + "', saturdayTo = '" + saturdayTo.Text + "', sundayFrom = '" + sundayFrom.Text + "', sundayTo = '" + sundayTo.Text + "', visitFrom = '" + visitFrom.Text + "', visitTo = '" + visitTo.Text + "', bestKnownFor = '" + bestknowFor.Text + "' WHERE hospitalID = '" + TextId.Text + "'"
            query.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Information updated successfully.');</script>")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: One clarification, I would like to ask here. Do you want to display servicesList checkboxes already selected on User Profile page? I didn't see that you populated that checkbox list on that page.

Comment: one suggestion, is there a specific reason you are not using Entity Framework or similar to interact with your database

Comment: @PiyushKhatri yes on profile page also user should be able to select services. I have it in my code but here I don't think so it need to post since post gets to lengthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below,

```
'Here I assume that, you will call PopulateServices to populate servicesList checkbox list
PopulateServices()

'You didn't mention fieldName, so I assume that field in database is : 
'savedServices - This will be li tags like, <li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li>

'Now loop through all items within checkbox list
For Each chk As ListItem In servicesList.Items
    'You need to check whether this item saved in database or not?
    'If item already saved in database, display as selected
    If savedServices.Contains("<li>" & chk.Text & "</li>") Then
        'display item as selected
        chk.selected = true
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This should work, can you debug code and try to see what exactly happen? I tested above code.

Comment: I think you placed code at incorrect place. Why did you place it in update info. You want to display checkboxes checked when we display it. So it should be in page load.

Comment: I placed it on load. If I logout & login back to same account then it gets unselect

Comment: Strange. Can you please debug and check if you get correct value from database? I don't see any problem with for loop. Is it possible if you can show me your problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105352/discussion-between-stupid-romeo-and-piyush-khatri).